# Visibility modifier with abstract method signatures in Java

Tags: java, keyword, modifier

Quick question:

Is the proper syntax:

```
public abstract void myMethod();
```

OR

```
abstract public void myMethod();
```

... The difference being the order of the keywords `public` and `abstract`.

Both compile without warnings, but which is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [JLS section 8.1.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.1)

```
ClassModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private
    abstract static final strictfp
```

> If two or more class modifiers appear in a class declaration, then it
>   is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order
>   consistent with that shown above in the production for ClassModifier.

Answer (score 2):

Either is "proper". The difference is a matter of style. I prefer the first.

Answer (score 2):

Both are syntactically correct but

```java
public abstract void myMethod();
```

is more common. You usually declare the visibility first.

Answer (score 1):

Most common practice is `public abstract`. I can't actually recall any example or book or any code I've worked with that does the opposite.